# Why is adding a FK constraint slow in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, foreign-key

I'm doing some experimentation in MySQL 5.1.53 and I've run across a case that I just don't understand.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    `pk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `fk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `pk_A` (`pk`),
    KEY `idx_fk` (`fk`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

SET foreign_key_checks=0;

ALTER TABLE `A` ADD FOREIGN KEY `idx_fk` (`fk`) REFERENCES `parent` (`pk`);
```

As far as I can tell, this should only add the constraint to the table meta-data for future data enforcement and ought to be an O(1) operation - we've turned off actually checking the constraint with "SET foreign_key_checks=0" and it should be using the idx_fk index (specified in the ADD FOREIGN KEY clause - possibly redundant) so it shouldn't have to create anything or iterate through the data in any way.

And yet that operation gets slower the larger the table when I run the ALTER TABLE.

What is it doing and why is that slow?

Comment: It needs to validate the foreign key, so for every row in `A` it needs to check if the referenced row in `parent` does exist.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  I thought I turned that off with the foreign_key_checks=0 statement.  Does that flag really mean, "check but ignore"?

Comment: May be the ALTER action rather than the foreign key addition. Consider this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424543/alter-table-without-locking-the-entire-table) and notes on MySQL < 5.6

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    `pk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `fk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
    KEY `idx_fk` (`fk`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

SET foreign_key_checks=0;

ALTER TABLE `A` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_idx_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`fk`) REFERENCES `parent` (`pk`);
```

added the CONSTRAINT keyword to explicitly specify the name of the foreign key constraint as fk_idx_fk. This ensures that the foreign key constraint has a unique name.